# Saving data table into an array throws null

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I'm having a problem when passing the information from a table to a bidimensional Array

```
for (int i=0; i < DefaultTableModel.getRowCount(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < DefaultTableModel.getColumnCount(); j++) {
        dataConteo[i][j]=DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(i,j);
    }
}
```

I completely fill the table and still im getting an error in

```
dataConteo[i][j]=DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(i,j);
```

with `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Nambari `model` definitely isn't null at that point, you would get an `NPE` in the first line if it was. But `dataConteo` or `dataConteo[i]` can be.

Comment: can we have error stack trace please ?

Comment: @biziclop: Yeah, I think you are correct. Removing my comment.

Comment: We need to see some code related to `dataConteo`'s initialization or `model`'s structure to spot where might be the `null` value be, otherwise we're just guessing. In particular I'm really curious to see your `model#getValueAt` method.

Comment: model its the DefaultTableModel sorry for not explaining it editing it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `model` isn't `null`....

Before the `for` loop, did you allocate the `dataConteo` array? Replace `Type` with the actual type.

```
Type[][] dataConteo = new Type[model.getRowCount()][model.getColumnCount()];
```

Comment: I had to allocate it that was the problem... its weird because it was working yesterday, maybe i deleted that line without noticing it. Thanks a lot.